# Selected Combo box items listed in a listview

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, listview, combobox

I want to list selected combo box items in a listView by using LINQ to SQL.
With my understanding the coding I have should work but it doesnt.(This coding should only display the CB items in the listview)

```
string pname = cbItem.SelectedItem.ToString();
listview.ItemsSource = DC.tblProducts.Where(p => p.ProductName == pname);
```

I basically want to make like a shopping cart but only to display the items that are selected thank you.

Comment: What problem you are facing using above snippet?

Comment: Are you getting data in the table(DC.tblProducts) where you try to put filter? What is DC.tblProducts? Is it a DataSet or EF object?

Comment: Could you post some code indicating the properties of the objects you have in cbItem? You've ToString'd the entire object rather than just the name, which should cause the Where to return null. Your question suggests that you're trying to list selected item*s*, plural. ComboBox.SelectedItem will only bind to a single object, not a collection - if you're using some kind of custom/3rd party multiselect combobox then the XAML for that is likely to be key to getting a good answer.

Comment: @AyyappanSubramanian the DC.tblProducts is a DataClassessDataContext sorry I am new with this dont know what you call it.

Comment: @goobering it makes sense what will be the best tool to use when listing 'collection' of objects?

Comment: Common choices are ListBox or ListView.

Comment: @goobering I dont think my problem is the selecteditem because choosing one item doesnt display either. I used a break point and it shows the combo box item that I have chosen shows 'Count 3' but in the listview it shows 'Count 0'. I did try to 'toString' only the name but still gives me the same results?

Comment: If you're trying to use the Items.Count property to figure out which items are selected then it's probably time for a breather. I think what you should do at this point is pause for reflection, do a little more research on the thing you're trying to achieve, and then perhaps come back and ask a different question. Here's a good solution on how to bind multiple selections from a ListBox: http://blog.scrappydog.com/2009/06/simple-method-of-binding-selected.html .

Comment: @goobering I did research a little bit more and found a simple solution that works, thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1):

I think that your problem lies here:

```
listview.ItemsSource = DC.tblProducts.Where(p => p.ProductName == pname);
```

From Microsoft's documentation on Enumerable.Where, emphasis mine (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534803%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> This method is implemented by using deferred execution. The immediate
>   return value is an object that stores all the information that is
>   required to perform the action. *The query represented by this method
>   is not executed until the object is enumerated either by calling its
>   GetEnumerator method directly or by using foreach in Visual C#* or For
>   Each in Visual Basic.

The LINQ statement has been defined but not evaluated, and as such doesn't have a value that ItemsSource can figure out. Try:

```
string pname = cbItem.SelectedItem.ToString();
var result = DC.tblProducts.Where(p => p.ProductName == pname);

var myList = new List<TblProductType>();
foreach(var v in result)
{
    myList.Add(v);
}
listview.ItemsSource = myList;
```